# Could there be a planet just as the Earth, but bigger?

Tags: earth, planets

Could there be a planet twice or thrice the size of Earth but while being the same? and by the same I mean, hosting the same life as Earth, having a day last 24 hours and a year 365 days.

Basically, could there be a bigger Earth? What would be needed to replicate Earth but in a bigger planet?

Comment: Orbits are easy. However any rocky/metallic planet will have a specific gravity of 2–7 grams/cm$^3$, and gravity will increase with mass; how strongly are you attached to earth's surface gravity of one $g$? (pun intended)

Comment: length of year? yes. Length of day? yes. 2-3 times bigger? Yes. host the same form of life? no. Earth forms of life are specifically adapted for our level of gravity, our level of atmosphere, etc. On this massive planet, the atmosphere would be heavier and the gravity would be stronger. You would get a lot more bird-like animals, short plants, and animals in general with less breathing capacity and frequency. It would be as difficult for them to live on Earth as us to live on Mars (assuming Mars' air was the same ratio of gases as Earth)